# Expand regex to require minimum 9 digits

Tags: regex

How can I expand this regular expression to require a minimum of 9 digits `[0-9]`?

```
var re = /^[+](\(?\+?[0-9]*\)?)?[0-9_\- \(\)]*$/ ///^(\(?\+?[0-9]*\)?)?[0-9_\- \(\)]*$/  
return re.test(phone);
```

If I change the expression to the following it complains its an invalid regex:

```
/^[+](\(?\+?[0-9]*\)?)?[0-9_\- \(\)]*$/ ///^(\(?\+?[0-9]*\)?)?[0-9_\- \(\)]{9,}*$/
```

Comment: `\d{9}`, actually.

Comment: What's the input?

Comment: `return re.test(phone) && phone.replace(/\D+/g, '').length >= 9;`

Comment: Or do you only need a single regex for that?

Comment: *"If I change the expression to the following it complains its an invalid regex:"* I think the end of that regex has too many quantifiers: `{9,}*` means: *"9 or more, zero or more"*

Answer (score 0):

A fast way to cause a failure if 9 digits are not found would be using a lookahead. It doesn't need to pass a test and then look for another condition. All in one go:

```
^(?=(?:\D*\d){9})[+](\(?\+?[0-9]*\)?)?[0-9_\- \(\)]*$
```

Regex added:

```
(?=(?:\D*\d){9})
```